# UILabel subclass

Tags: cocoa, subclassing

I know that this is a newbie question but I am a newbie so here goes:

I wish to use Chalkduster font quite a lot throughout my app (buttons, labels etc) and have tried subclassing UILabel to achieve this.  I have the following in Default.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Default : UILabel
{
UILabel *theLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *theLabel;

@end
```

and this in my .m:

```
#import "Default.h"

@implementation Default

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code


UIFont *custom = [[UIFont alloc] init];

custom = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:18];

self.font = custom;


NSLog(@"h");
}
return self;
}

@end
```

When I change the class in interface builder and run, I'm not seeing the Chalkduster font.  I'd appreciate a hand in getting this set up as I believe it will save me a lot of time.
Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some problems to fix:

1) You're mixing up the idea of `Default` **being** a label and `Default` **containing** a label.  To subclass, get rid of the property inside your class and make your changes to `self` rather than `theLabel` (inside the `if (self) {` section).

2) Anything you code after an unconditional `return` isn't going to get executed...and I'm surprised the compiler didn't complain about those statements.

Edit: ...and one more thing that just dawned on me.

3) If you're loading from a xib or storyboard, the initialization is done by `initWithCoder:` instead of `initWithFrame:`, so:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:18];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I also tried changing theLabel to self to no avail.  I'm sure I'm missing something extremely simple here...

Comment: What does the new code look like?  If you change `self`'s font when it's created and use `Default` in IB, thing's should work.

Comment: I moved the return self down as described above, I've also deleted the property and variable in .h. The @synthesize has been deleted too. I tried it with an NSLog statement and it doesn't appear. I've also included the #import statement for default within the view controller... Am I still missing something simple? Make no assumptions of my stupidity or otherwise :)

Comment: Can't get to my computer to copy exact code but will later if that helps?

Comment: See sample code added.  Creating a class containing that method and assigning it as the class of a `UILabel` in a storyboard works for me.

Comment: The change from initWithFrame to initWithCoder worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

First of all I don't think that You're subclassing `UILabel` correctlly. So I made tutorial for You explaining how to do it. **You don't need to IBOutlet object which is subclassed. JUST CALL IT WITH SELF.** for example: `self.font = ...` If You want to subclass `UILabel` do this:

Create new class with title *myLabel* like this:

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyLabel : UILabel {

}

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "MyLabel.h"

@implementation MyLabel

-(void)awakeFromNib {

    UIFont *custom = [[UIFont alloc] init];
    custom = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Chalkduster" size:18];

    self.font = custom;
}

@end
```

Now select Your label in storyboard and go to **indentity inspector** and in Custom Class select created class above. Like this:

[image: Screenshot]

**Output:**

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Note:** Don't forget to release custom because You are allocating it.

Comment: This also worked for me.  Thank you very much for your efforts.  This is an excellent tutorial

Answer (score 3):

Move the `return self;` three lines down. You return from the init method before you do your custom initialization.

**Edit** to reflect new information from comment:

When deserializing the view from a nib you also have to override `initWithCoder:`

Comment: I tried moving the line as described, it still didn't work.  Do I have to do something in Interface Builder also?